# How do I automount a LUKS partition on iscsi at boot?

Tags: boot, lvm, centos-7, luks, iscsi

I have a partition on a CentOS7 machine that is mounted from iSCSI as follows:

iSCSI -> LVM -> LUKS -> XFS

/etc/crypttab is configured as follows with a key:

```
home_vmail UUID="b79e45cf-89aa-40f2-9fb1-f62f0c795e88" /etc/keyfile
```

/etc/fstab is configured as follows:

```
/dev/mapper/home_vmail  /home/vmail     xfs _netdev     1 2
```

iSCSI runs fine on boot, the LVM is detected successfully, and the LUKS is correctly unlocked. The last step - the automount of the partition - is missing.

Working around the problem is as simple as manually running "mount -a", but I need this to run on boot.

What option do you need to use to mount network based filesystems automatically on boot?

Update: Redhat publishes an obsolete solution for RHEL6 at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3889 that makes mention of a "netfs" service that either does not exist or is undocumented in RHEL7/CentOS7.

Update 2: Further digging shows that services are booting in the wrong order. Specifically, iscsi is being started before networking. Bug raised here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1368610